# Hook query retruning empty object inside useEffect but not after it Why?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I have a query hook from which I wish to populate a state variable with data. The problem is, within useEffect the query is being returned as an {} object but after useEffect properly returns data (See image). I attempted to place useEffect after all the variable definitions but that issued a hook render error. What am I overlooking here and how do I resolve this?

```
  // Single Item Query
  const { data: singledItemData, error: errorSingleItem, loading: loadingSingleItem } = useQuery(
    SINGLE_ITEM_QUERY, {
      variables: {
        id: props.id,
      }
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("singledItemData in useEffect = ", singledItemData);
    if (singledItemData.item) {
      setColor(singledItemData.item.color.name);
    }
  }, []);

  // User hook variables
  if (!user) return null;
  if (user.error) return <Error error={user.error} />;

  // Single Item Query variables

  if (loadingSingleItem) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (!singledItemData.item) return <p>No Item Found for ID {props.id}</p>;

  console.log("Single Item Data = ", singledItemData);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a component using `useQuery` mounts it starts a network request which is asynchronous. Your `useEffect` hook however is executed once after the component has mounted (due to the empty dependency list). At this time the request most likely hasn't even finished so no data is available. As soon as the request finishes your component will re-render again (triggered by the state update in the `useQuery` hook) with the received data. But this time your `useEffect` callback will not be called again. Add `singledItemData` to the dependency list to see the change or just `console.log` in the outer scope so see the changes of every render.

So this is no bug but the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are passing an empty array as the second parameter of useEffect hook. This will make the hook only run once, on mount. If you want to run every time singledItemData changes, you need to pass it in the array.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("singledItemData in useEffect = ", singledItemData);
    if (singledItemData.item) {
      setColor(singledItemData.item.color.name);
    }
  }, [singledItemData]);
```